# Configuring PayPal webhook URL dynamically in .NET application

Tags: .net, paypal, webhooks

I'm working on integrating PayPal webhooks into my .NET application, and I need to dynamically set up the webhook URL without relying on the PayPal Developer Dashboard. I've followed the documentation and set up a controller action to handle webhook events ([HttpPost("/webhooks/paypal")]), but it doesn't seem to be working as expected.

Could someone provide guidance on how to properly configure and handle PayPal webhook URLs within an .NET application without using the Developer Dashboard? I've already ensured that the webhook URL in my code matches the actual endpoint where my application is deployed, but I'm still encountering issues.

Any insights, tips, or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

1.Implemented the controller action to handle PayPal webhook events.
2.Ensured that the webhook URL in my code accurately reflects the endpoint of my deployed application.
3.Verified that the PayPal SDK is properly configured within my application.
**What Actually Resulted:**
Despite these efforts, the PayPal webhook does not seem to trigger the controller action as expected. I've checked the logs and tested the webhook URL, but it appears that the webhook events are not being received by my application.

Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Specific webhook event types, or `*` for all event types, need to be subscribed for each REST App for which they are desired. Up to 10 URLs can be subscribed per app.

Webhook sbscriptions can be managed either in the developer dashboard interface for the App, or using the [webhooks management API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/webhooks/v1/#webhooks_post). Your question does not indicate that you have set up subscriptions.

Comment: I'm trying to subscribe to PayPal webhook events programmatically, but I'm not sure how to retrieve a list of all available event types. Currently, I'm using the wildcard (*) to subscribe to all events, but I'd like to have a comprehensive list to choose from. Can anyone provide guidance on how to fetch and display all the available event types in PayPal using the PayPal API or any other method? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Point your web browser to https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/webhooks/event-names/